# Multiple Column Group count linq dataset

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm not a regular user of LINQ so this question might be as dumb as possible for an expert :)

I have a table in a dataset as below

```
Column1     OffLoc
01/02/2016  Johannesburg   
01/02/2016  Johannesburg
02/02/2016  Moscow
02/02/2016  Johannesburg
02/02/2016  Johannesburg
03/02/2016  Johannesburg
03/02/2016  Moscow
03/02/2016  Moscow
03/02/2016  Bogota
04/02/2016  Barcelona
04/02/2016  Johannesburg
04/02/2016  Singapore
04/02/2016  Singapore
04/02/2016  Singapore
05/02/2016  Singapore
05/02/2016  Singapore
05/02/2016  Singapore
10/02/2016  Singapore
10/02/2016  Singapore
10/02/2016  Singapore
10/02/2016  Singapore
10/02/2016  Singapore
```

I would like to have like the below

```
Column1      Offloc        Count
01/02/2016 - Johannesburg - 2
02/02/2016 - Moscow - 1
02/02/2016 - Johannesburg - 2
03/02/2016 - Johannesburg - 1
03/02/2016 - Moscow - 2
03/02/2016 - Bogota - 1
...
```

I tried to use this example [Linq1](https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/how-to-create-a-multiple-column-group-by-using-linq-to-entities-vb-net/), but im using dataset and refrain from copying the data to a list and then performing the Tasks. I also tried following Code:

```
Dim oQuery = _
    From oRow In ds.Table("AuditLog").AsEnumerable() _
    Group By _
            Column1DT = oRow("Column1"), _
            OffLocDT = oRow("OffLoc") _
    Into Total
```

But I dont know how to proceed from here. Please help me. Im using vb.net, because the online converters do not convert very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already done the grouping correctly. Next step, you can project the query into an anonymous type containing all the needed information, for example :

```
Dim oQuery = _
    From oRow In ds.Table("AuditLog").AsEnumerable() _
    Group By _
            Column1DT = oRow("Column1"), _
            OffLocDT = oRow("OffLoc") _
    Into Total = Group
    Select New With
    {
        Key .Column1 = Column1DT,
        Key .OffLoc = OffLocDT,
            .Count = G.Count()
    }
```

[**Full working demo example :**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0y4SZ4)

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(DateTime))
dt.Columns.Add("OffLoc", GetType(String))
dt.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2016, 1, 2), "Johannesburg")
dt.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2016, 1, 2), "Johannesburg")
dt.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2016, 1, 3), "Jakarta")
dt.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2016, 1, 3), "Jakarta")
dt.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2016, 1, 3), "Jakarta")

Dim result = From oRow In dt.AsEnumerable()
             Group By
                    Column1DT = oRow("Column1"),
                    OffLocDT = oRow("OffLoc")
             Into G = Group
             Select New With
             {
                Key .Column1 = Column1DT,
                Key .OffLoc = OffLocDT,
                    .Count = G.Count()
             }

For Each item As Object In result
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

**output :**

```
{ Column1 = 1/2/2016 12:00:00 AM, OffLoc = Johannesburg, Count = 2 }
{ Column1 = 1/3/2016 12:00:00 AM, OffLoc = Jakarta, Count = 3 }
```

Comment: Thank you Har07, your code worked like a Dodge Hellcat (means impressive)

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go.

```
Dim list = (From g In ds.Tables("AuditLog").AsEnumerable()
                  Group By
                         col1 = g("Column1"),
                         col2 = g("OffLoc")
                  Into X = Group
                  Select New With
                  {
                     Key .Column1 = col1,
                     Key .OffLoc = col2,
                         .Count = X.Count()
                  }).ToList()
```